# What is the purpose of the "description" field in JSON Schemas?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm not sure what the purpose of a JSON Schema "description" field is.  Does the field serve as a space to comment? Does the field serve as an ID?

```
{
    "id": "http://www.noodle.org/entry-schema#",
    "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "schema for online courses",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "institution": {
            "type": "object",
           "$ref" : "#/definitions/institution" 
        },
        "person": {
            "type": "object",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/person"
            }   
    "definitions": {        
        "institution": {
            "description": "University",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name":{"type":"string"},
                "url":{
                    "format": "uri",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "descriptionofinstitution":{"type":"string"},
                "location": {
                    "description": "location",
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
                }
        }
```

}

Comment: Could you post an example of that?

Answer (score 19):

According to the JSON-Schema specification (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor98), the purpose of the "description" (and "title") fields is to decorate a user interface with information about the data produced by this user interface. A title will preferrably be short, whereas a description will provide explanation about the purpose of the instance described by this schema.

Comment: It can also be very handy for generating documentation directly from json-schema files!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably some additional explanation, in order to enhance the knowledge concerning the specific entry, if the id is not enough. Of course it doesn't affect the behavior of the code as code itself